# Jenkins pipeline is throwing Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ecs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/"

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-ecs

We have AWS ECS Fargate running taskdefinitions and tasks. I wanted to perform deployment to AWS ECS by updating task definition with new Docker image using Jenkins. I have create a script for this on my Jenkins machine. I can run this and update the task definition. But using Jenkins the script is giving error. I have ECR configurations in Jenkins and I can push images to AWS ECR. But scripts for describing task definitions gives error "Could not connect to the endpoint URL" error".

Initially I was getting credentials error. I resolved this by running aws config for jenkins.

I used withAWS in jenkins pipeline. Still getting the same error.

I tried the solutions provided in the sites, but did not resolve the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add more info so we can help. Add the Jenkins script if possible, what you get from logs.. etc

Comment: Please add the error log and the script if possible